# Not Found Error On Google Geolocation

Tags: json, google-api, geolocation, google-geolocation

When i have put the url below to my browser adress bar i get a 'not found' text.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=API_‌​KEY
```

I have registered my app at console and get a api key for that application. I have even provide my credit card data at console and started my trial membership.

I am expecting that it returns me some json. But it doesn't. Why google is not recognize my api key and gives me not found page?

Answer (score 11):

The URL `https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=API_‌​KEY` is for sending `POST` requests. Since you are navigating it directly in your browser, it won't return any result.

You need to send a `POST` request with `Request body` to get the desired result.

Please refer to the [Documentation page for Geolocation requests](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#requests) to get more information on creating your `Request`.